# How much money can I make with my Top Tier Berries as a Botany Researcher?

Tags: optimization, pokemon-tabletop-united

The Green Thumbs edge gives you the ability to grow Tier 1 berries and Apricorns. The Botany Researcher's Top Tier Berries gives you this:

> You may grow additional Berries and Herbs, depending on the higher of your General Education or Survival Rank.
>
> - Novice: You may grow Tier 2 Berries
> - Adept: You may grow Mental Herbs, Power Herbs, White Herbs, and Tiny Mushrooms.
> - Expert: You may grow Revival Herbs, Energy Roots, Big Mushrooms, and Tier 3 Berries
> - Master: Increase the Soil Quality of all your plants by +1.

Here's the sell prices:

| Tier | Item | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cheri Berry, Chesto Berry, Pecha Berry, Rawst Berry, Aspear Berry, Oran Berry, Persim Berry, Razz Berry (and similar). | $150 |
| A | Apricorn Balls (made from Apricorns with Apricon Balls edge and Poké Ball Tool Box) | $800 |
| 2: Novice | Lum Berry, Sitrus Berry, Figy Berry (And similar), Liechi Berry (and similar), Pamtre Berry (and similar), Enigma Berry, Lansat Berry, Micle Berry, Cornn Berry, Magost Berry, Rabuta Berry, Nomel Berry, Spelon Berry, Jaboca Berry, Rowap Berry, Starf Berry | $250 |
| 2.5: Adept | Mental Herb, Power Herb, White Herb | $300 |
| 3: Expert | Leppa Berry, Pomeg Berry (and similar), Occa Berry (and similar), Custap Berry, Kee Berry, Maranga Berry | $500 |

Here is a list of plants:

| Plant Type | Yield Roll |
| --- | --- |
| Tier 1 Berries | 1d3-1 |
| Apricorns | 1d2-2 |
| Mental Herbs, White Herbs, Power Herbs, Tiny Mushrooms & Tier 2 Berries | 1d3-2 |
| Revival Herbs, Energy Roots, Big Mushrooms, Balm Mushrooms & Tier 3 Berries | 1d4-3 |

(Note: There does not seem to be a way to grow Balm Mushrooms in soil. The book only says that Pokémon can produce them, which doesn't use this table at all.)

To throw in another variable, you can also buy mulch for $200 to raise soil quality by 1.

If you can sell items for half price, how much will you make? What's the most profitable way to grow items?

Answer (score 2):

I made this table using [AnyDice](https://anydice.com/):

| Soil Quality | Berry #1 Tier | Berry #2 Tier | $ Benefit of growing #1 over #2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | -33.33 |
| 0 | 3 | 2 | 20.83 |
| 0 | 3 | 1 | -12.50 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | -25.00 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 62.50 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 37.50 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 25.00 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 125.00 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 150.00 |

This is the mean money per yield roll. "Tier 2.5" is always better than 2 but worse than 3.

If you can make Apricorn balls, doing so and selling them is always more profitable than growing and selling any berry (except obviously when the soil won't yield any Apricorns). You can get $75 more from selling balls grown from soil quality 1 than growing Tier 3 berries, and $225 more doing the same but at soil quality 2.

I also determined that using mulch always makes you lose money, with the exception of when you can grow an Apricorn and make it into a ball. Lower tier berries don't sell for enough to make spending $200 worth it, and even tier 3 berries don't yield enough berries per day for it to be worthwhile: you would need to be able to get to soil quality 3 in order to make a profit with it. Upgrading 0 soil quality to 1 for Apricorns breaks even (so is a waste of time and energy). Upgrading 1 soil quality to 2 for Apricorns is a $200 average profit per yield.

Code for the table:

```
function: nonnegative X:n {
  if X > 0 {
   result: X
  }
  else {
   result: 0
  }
}

output [nonnegative (1d3 - 2)] * 125 - (1d3 - 1) * 75 named "SQ 0: T2 vs T1"
output [nonnegative (1d4 - 3)] * 250 - [nonnegative (1d3 - 2)] * 125 named "SQ 0: T3 vs T2"
output [nonnegative (1d4 - 3)] * 250 - (1d3 - 1) * 75 named "SQ 0: T3 vs T1"

output (1d3 - 1) * 125 - (1d3) * 75 named "SQ 1: T2 vs T1"
output [nonnegative (1d4 - 2)] * 250 - (1d3 - 1) * 125 named "SQ 1: T3 vs T2"
output [nonnegative (1d4 - 2)] * 250 - (1d3) * 75 named "SQ 1: T3 vs T1"

output 1d3 * 125 - (1d3 + 1) * 75 named "SQ 2: T2 vs T1"
output (1d4 - 1) * 250 - 1d3 * 125 named "SQ 2: T3 vs T2"
output (1d4 - 1) * 250 - (1d3 + 1) * 75 named "SQ 2: T3 vs T1"
```

Tier 2.5 comparisons:

```
output [nonnegative (1d3 - 2)] * 125 - [nonnegative (1d3 - 2)] * 150 named "SQ 0: T2 vs T2.5"
output (1d3 - 1) * 125 - (1d3 - 1) * 150 named "SQ 1: T2 vs T2.5"
output (1d3) * 125 - (1d3) * 150 named "SQ 2: T2 vs T2.5"

output [nonnegative (1d4 - 3)] * 250 - [nonnegative (1d3 - 2)] * 150 named "SQ 0: T3 vs T2.5"
output [nonnegative (1d4 - 2)] * 250 - (1d3 - 1) * 150 named "SQ 1: T3 vs T2.5"
output (1d4 - 1) * 250 - (1d3) * 150 named "SQ 2: T3 vs T2.5"
```

Apricorn comparison:

```
output (1d2 - 1) * 400 - (1d4 - 2) * 250 named "SQ 1: A vs T3"
output (1d2) * 400 - (1d4 - 1) * 250 named "SQ 2: A vs T3"
```

Code to evaluate fertilizer:

```
output [nonnegative (1d4 - 3)] * 250 - ([nonnegative (1d4 - 2)] * 250 - 200) named "unfertilized SQ0 T3 vs fertilized SQ1 T3"
output [nonnegative (1d4 - 2)] * 250 - ([nonnegative (1d4 - 1)] * 250 - 200) named "unfertilized SQ1 T3 vs fertilized SQ2 T3"
output 0 - ((1d2 - 1) * 400 - 200) named "unfertilized SQ0 A vs fertilized SQ1 A"
output (1d2 - 1) * 400 - (1d2 * 400 - 200) named "unfertilized SQ1 A vs fertilized SQ2 A"
```

Note: In the code, SQ is soil quality, T means what tier of berry, A means an Apricorn that's grown and made into a ball.